# Fractional Scaling when using NVIDIA high-performance mode

Tags: nvidia, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-prime

I have Ubuntu 19.10 and installed NVIDIA proprietary drivers.
When I switch to Intel graphics, I can use fractional scaling feature. But when I switch to NVIDIA using `prime-select` command, display scale returns to 100%. Is it possible to have fractional scaling when using high-performance NVIDIA graphics?
Edit:
Laptop Model: Acer Aspire 7 A715-71G-71Y3
NVIDIA Card: GTX 1050 Ti Mobile
NVIDIA Driver: nvidia-driver-435 (proprietary, tested)

I also need to state that switch happens when I reboot the machine (NVIDIA settings app tells me to restart the device after changing prime settings).
Also, when I enable fractional scaling again, and choose 125%, it scales 200% instead of 125%.

Comment: @K7AAY I added the info

Comment: Are you using the latest drivers, version 441.87  https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/156282 ?

Comment: @K7AAY I'm using driver 435, isn't that more recent than 375?

Comment: I checked nvidia website, 435 is the latest driver for "Linux Short Lived"

Comment: @K7AAY Saw that. I will install it and let you know about the results.

Comment: @K7AAY I downloaded the new driver (440.44) and installed it. It actually corrupted everything. Now I only can boot into ubuntu if I'm selecting Intel graphics. I guess the 440.44 driver is not yet ready.

Comment: Drat. Back to 435, then.

Comment: @K7AAY I finally managed to get 440 working. Now I can boot with NVIDIA high performance mode but editing display scales completely breaks the desktop. For example the left dock bar goes away, ...

Comment: Sounds like a genuine grade-A bug to report at Launchpad.net